# appProj.VisualReportsNewTemplate creates no new Excel table with an pivot table in it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I will generate a pivot table in Excel out of MSProject with VBA.

The following methode worked in the past but jet it throws out a failure:
appProj.VisualReportsNewTemplate PjVisualReportsTemplateType:=pjExcel, PjVisualReportsCubeType:=pjTaskTP, ReportAlLFields:=False, PjVisualReportsDataLevel:=pjLevelMonths

In the past it opened a new Excel table with a pivot table in it, but now there is an unknown error and I don't know what has changed in between!

Has anyone an idea how I can fix it?

Best regards
Uwe

There is nothing I know and will help, I guess!